# PHPStorm autocomplete with Symfony routing with annotations

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm

I'm using latest version of PHPStorm 10 and want to use annotations for my Symfony 2.8.1 routes. I want to use PHPStorm's autocomplete feature to autocomplete my routes in twig files, but they are autocompleted wrong. I'm using both Symfony2 plugin and PHP Annotations.

Routing file

```
#app/config/routing.yml
ParkResortBundle:
    resource: "@ParkResortBundle/Controller"
    prefix: /
    type: annotation
```

My controller with one route

```
namespace ParkResortBundle\Controller;
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @return Response
     * @Route("/")
     */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        return $this->render('ParkResortBundle:Pages:firstpage.html.twig');
    }
}
```

This should normally generate `park_resort_default_index` but instead it generates `parkresort_default_index` and my PHPStorm finds and autocompletes it with the underscore. I've also ran debug:router to confirm and it indeed finds the route and it does work without the underscore. But I want it with the underscore.

[Even in the docs it says](http://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/SensioFrameworkExtraBundle/annotations/routing.html#route-name):

`sensio_blog_post_index` is the route for SensioBlogBundle's Postcontroller index action. It puts an underscore in between the camelcase capital letters.

What did I do wrong?

Comment: PHPStorm uses the appDevUrlGenerator.php located in the dev cache folder to autocomplete routes. Check it to make sure symfony generates correct route names. #Settings > Other settings > Symfony plugin - Path to urlGenerator.php

Comment: That field has 'var/cache/dev/appDevUrlGenerator.php' in it

Comment: Check it's contents. Also you can name your routes to almost anything. It's good practice to name them explicitly. `@Route("/", name="some_route_name")`

Comment: The generator contains the routes without the undescore. Why are they generated like that? The docs say that they should contain underscores by default.

Comment: According to the source code it converts the namespaced classname to lowercase, changes the namespace separator to underscore, and removes some keywords. https://github.com/symfony/symfony/blob/582f4753a343f230fbe18b4e9a0747d48351ddfb/src/Symfony/Component/Routing/Loader/AnnotationClassLoader.php#L198
 My guess it that the example @SensioBlugBundle namespace would be \Sensio\Bundle\BlogBundle, simirarly to \Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle

Comment: So I have no other option than to name each of my routes? That sucks.

Comment: You don't need to, the generated route names will start with `parkresort` not with `park_resort`, that is all.

Comment: I know, but I cannot use PHPStorm's autocomplete feature. That was the issue here, I have to manually write all of them rather than write the first few letters, press tab and be done with it.

Comment: *"I know, but I cannot use PHPStorm's autocomplete feature."* It's not PhpStorm itself that provides Symfony integration/support here -- it's all handled by [Symfony support plugin](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin). I personally do use Symfony and this plugin .. but maybe you are still missing "PHP Annotation" plugin (that works with annotations)?

Comment: I do have both those plugins.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will add your cases. see external issues

https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/673

EDIT:
fixed in version "0.11.109"